# Help Center, "What types of questions should I avoid asking" is missing recommendations

Tags: support, help-center

The Help Center's [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) is missing recommendations. For example, there's no text that coincides with this close reason:

[image]

Would it be possible to add the relevant text to the Help Center topic?

Comment: The very first line in that page links to the on-topic page, as a requirement before anything else. And the on-topic page does list that reason.

Comment: [Help Center ->  What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:
 ...Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Mat still, we should have the information in as many places as we need. People are not going to read everything.

Comment: @Scimonster: the people who actually care do read. Most don't, no matter how many times you duplicate the information, even if you make them click through it.